# How do you prevent javascript from completing brackets in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, resharper

When I type "{" in a javascript file it autocompletes the "}"

I do however, have ReSharper, but I have disabled the options for it already, and it does not autocomplete in C#, just in javascript.

Any ideas? Not sure if it is Visual Studio or ReSharper doing this.

**From Resharper Options**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like Visual Studio is to blame. I'd try to turn off "Format completed line on Enter" in VS options, it may affect this behavior.

Comment: See my edit.  I was able to turn off brace completion in Javascript for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio option.  Under Tools > Options, you can go to Text Editor > JavaScript > Formatting.  Uncheck the option that says "Automatically format completed block on }"

EDIT:

Are you using Productivity Power Tools? It has an "Automatic Brace Completion" feature that can be turned off. You'll have to restart VS for it to take effect.

Comment: I saw that as well, but does not help... will add that to images

Comment: I did, maybe it still has the option on after removing, let me try reinstalling it and disable it, see if that helps...

Comment: BAH, found it.. it was Web Essentials Addon, had no idea that addon even had that feature!... Thanks, I'll give it to you since you lead me there